# Create Header file in C

Tags: c, header-files

I included C classes in my main class called `client.c`.

```
#include "asn_application.h"
#include "asn_codecs_prim.h"
#include "asn_codecs.h"
#include "asn_internal.h"
#include "asn_system.h"
#include....
```

When I compile I have this error

```
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/BIT_STRING.d" \
    -MT"src/BIT_STRING.d" -o "src/BIT_STRING.o" "../src/BIT_STRING.c"
../src/BIT_STRING.c:5:26: warning: asn_internal.h: No such file or directory
../src/BIT_STRING.c:6:24: warning: BIT_STRING.h: No such file or directory
../src/BIT_STRING.c:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
'__attribute__' before 'asn_DEF_BIT_STRING_tags'
../src/BIT_STRING.c:15: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
'__attribute__' before 'asn_DEF_BIT_STRING_specs'
../src/BIT_STRING.c:20: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
'__attribute__' before 'asn_DEF_BIT_STRING'
../src/BIT_STRING.c:48: error: expected ')' before '*' token
../src/BIT_STRING.c:76: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
'__attribute__' before 'BIT_STRING_encode_xer'
../src/BIT_STRING.c:141: error: expected ')' before '*' token
make: *** [src/BIT_STRING.o] Error 1
```

It says `asn_internal.h`, `BIT_STRING.h` ... don't exist but the files are there. Maybe it's because I don't have a header file? 
I tried to create a `client.h`:

```
#ifndef client
#define client
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "asn_application.h"
#include "asn_codecs_prim.h"
#include "asn_codecs.h"
#include "asn_internal.h"
#include "asn_system.h"
#include "ber_decoder.h"
#include "ber_tlv_length.h"
#include "ber_tlv_tag.h"
#include "BIT_STRING.h"
#include "BOOLEAN.h"
#include "constr_SEQUENCE.h"
#include "constr_TYPE.h"
#include "constraints.h"
#include "der_encoder.h"
#include "INTEGER.h"
#include "Message01.h"
#include "Message02.h"
#include "Message03.h"
#include "Message02.h"
#include "Message04.h"
#include "NativeEnumerated.h"
#include "NativeInteger.h"
#include "OCTET_STRING.h"
#include "per_decoder.h"
#include "per_encoder.h"
#include "per_opentype.h"
#include "per_support.h"
#include "PrintableString.h"
#include "xer_decoder.h"
#include "xer_encoder.h"
#include "xer_support.h"

#endif
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.  What should I be doing?

Comment: As something of a sidenote, based on its name, your code should not need `asn_internal.h` unless you're writing the ASN code.  More relevantly, which directory contains the headers?  Did you specify it on the GCC command line?

Comment: BTW: the filenames in CAPITALS and in mixed_CASE are confusing and a recipe for disaster, IMHO.

Comment: It's in the same directory of client.c

Comment: _It's in the same directory as `client.c`_ … Then it appears you need a `-I../src` option on the compiler line to tell the compiler where to find header files.  _Or_ maybe it is `-Isrc`; the pathnames used in the command line split between `../src` and `src/`, which suggests some confusion.

Comment: It compile fine with the command line but how can I do it in eclipse ?

Comment: Ditch Eclipse and use a command line?  Investigate the questions tagged [tag:eclipse] and find out how to specify the correct location for headers in the command line.

Comment: I had the same problem when compiling from inside Xcode (not Eclipse): There you have to adjust your project's *Header Search Path* (akin to using option `-I` on the command line).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the directories to the include path

See the manual page http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

And note the -I flag

Might need to think about the -L flag and -l flag as well